# Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors: The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I realize that this question seems to come up frequently. I've gone through each one and tried many of the suggested solutions. One solution did seem to get me to a "working" state, but it does not seem like it addressed the actual underlying issue, but instead somehow worked around it. So, let me explain my scenario and what I've tried.

I'm writing an AspNet WebApi application that will be served up by IIS. My application is currently using convention based routing, as opposed to attribute routing. My application needs to handle CORS pre-flight requests (OPTIONS). I've installed the required Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package, from Nuget. Below are the versions of the AspNet packages that I'm using:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Based on my reading, the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package is supposed to add support for handling CORS pre-flight requests. This means I won't have to add manual OPTIONS action methods, etc - the nuget package brings that for me. So, I've configured the package so that it enables CORS for all available controllers, based on a commonly referenced blog post. To my understanding, this should be all that is needed for my application to begin responding to OPTIONS requests. Below is my configuration for completeness sake - it shows that I also configure some other things:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var jsonMapping = new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, true, "application/json");
        var corsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(jsonMapping);

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IFilterProvider), new UnityFilterProvider(UnityConfig.Container));

        config.EnableCors(corsAttribute);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Lastly, I've seen some reference to some items in the web.config regarding the OPTIONSVerbHandler. Mine is left at whatever the default value is, which is shown below ...

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Finally, with all of these items in place, it appears that my application still fails to handle OPTIONS requests. Using postman, I simply send an OPTIONS request to any of my endpoints and regardless of endpoint I receive the following 405 response ...

```
Allow →POST
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →76
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 14 Feb 2018 20:50:14 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNccmNvbGVcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHVkaW8gMjAxN1xQcm9qZWN0c1xQb3J0YWwuUkVTVFxQb3J0YWwuUkVTVFxhY2NvdW50XGF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZQ==?=

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}
```

Here's some of the things I've tried to fix this:

1. I tried removing the OPTIONSVerbHandler from web.config, which seemed to make no change.
2. I tried explicitly putting EnableCorsAttribute on individual action methods and controllers, which seemed to make no change.
3. I explicitly put HttpOptionsAttribute on an action method, which seemed to fix the issue. This seems like the incorrect approach, though, as that attribute is for saying that action method is for handling OPTIONS requests, which is not at all what I want. I thought Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package brings its own OPTIONS handler.
4. I tried switching to attribute-based routing, as opposed to the original convention-based routing. Didn't seem to change anything.

Does anybody know what could be causing this issue? It doesn't seem like my Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package is correctly wired up, or doing anything. The response has no CORS headers in it. It looks like AspNet doesn't think it has any OPTIONS handler in place, despite me enabling it in my configuration.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Have you tried creating a new simple version from scratch? Perhaps an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Not yet. Will do not. Current project is pretty new / minimal - only thing I've really added it auto dependency injection so maybe that's messing with something.

Comment: @KirkLarkin It look me a few days, but I found the time to make a [fresh AspNet project](https://github.com/ryancole/AspNetCorsNoWork/blob/master/TestCors/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs#L11) and add the Cors package. It still doesn't work. I get the `OPTIONS` is not allowed error. This is literally a fresh, empty AspNet template project with a controller added and the Cors package added. Nothing more. Does this package even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this question asked in several other locations. Most answers focus on web.config hacks, custom filter attributes, other custom code, etc, as the solution. I want to mark what ended up being the solution in my scenario, which I believe to be many of the other folks' scenarios ...

The `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package does indeed work and handle `OPTIONS` pre-flight requests. It only kicks into action when the appropriate CORS headers are present, though.

So, in my scenario, I was testing this using a tool, such as Postman. I was testing by sending explicit `OPTIONS` requests. Well, many of these tools don't send CORS pre-flight requests, and even then, when sending manual `OPTIONS` requests they do not include the required CORS headers that trigger the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` functionality.

So, in the end, for me, there was no technical issue or bug, it was a lack of knowledge about how the nuget package works. When I switched back over to my JavaScript project, and made the request across origin, using `fetch`, the requests worked. Chrome sends the pre-flight `OPTIONS`, with appropriate CORS headers.

So, make sure you're testing using appropriate CORS headers, if you're using a tool like Postman!

Comment: So, what are the required CORS headers it's looking for?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a CORS issue per se. It's your web server not allowing OPTIONS requests. I realize this isn't an answer, but it should help you get on the path to narrowing it down some more.

Comment: Don't think that's the case. If I add the [HttpOptionsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpoptionsattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to an action method, it "works." Although, that's not a fix for my issue, it does show that `OPTIONS` requests *can* make it through.

Comment: If this isn't an answer, you should be making it a comment. You have plenty enough reputation...

Comment: Mike, my thought was this MIGHT be the answer. I probably should have said "This might not be the answer...".